# Comparing cell values with a integer in pandas giving typeerror

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to compare values of each cell in a row with an integer like so:

```
df.loc[df['A'] <= 14, 'A']
```

All rows whose values are less than or equal to 14, but it shows an error like:

> ```
> TypeError : '<=' is not supported between instances of str and int
> ```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont have a data example as of now, but I input the dataset from a csv file straight to a dataframe and then I was trying to do this stuff

Comment: Ok, no problem. Your error is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `,` to empty space and convert to `int`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1,473','1,473','1,4', '1,2'],
                   'B':[2,4,5,5]})
print (df)
       A  B
0  1,473  2
1  1,473  4
2    1,4  5
3    1,2  5

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
s = df.loc[df['A'] <= 14, 'A']
print (s)
2    14
3    12
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

---

If use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `DataFrame` add parameter `thousands=','`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',', sep=';')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""A;B
1,473;2
1,473;4
1,4;5
1,2;5"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), thousands=',', sep=';')

print (df)
      A  B
0  1473  2
1  1473  4
2    14  5
3    12  5

s = df.loc[df['A'] <= 14, 'A']
print (s)
2    14
3    12
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Now it shows `ValueError : invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '1,473'`

Comment: I have input the values through a csv and that came in as strings and aren't comparable, I dont know what to do now

Comment: `thousands = ','` worked like charm, And one more thing how did you learn these kind of stuff or pandas, did you do it through the documentation or something else, please brief me

Comment: Glad can help, second solution is preferable - not replace is necessary.

Comment: Could you tell me as to how a beginner should start to learn pandas for data cleaning and analysis?

Comment: Hmmm, I answer a lot of question daily, so I learn myself. But if want some great stuff, I like [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas)

Comment: Hmmm, hard question. But in my opinion the best coding, coding and coding and finding solutions if have some problem. First I think many things are really hard for each of us, but later it is much better. First codes are worse, but later, with some experience your code will be better and better.

Comment: Will the semicolon work as a separator, because csv is comma separated and not semicolon separated

Comment: because ig good csv, all values are separated also `"1,4","4,677"`